# Loading camel routes in camel context runtime from database

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-routes

My routes are in the same xml format stored into database as we write in spring files. I would like to know how to parse them into RouteDefinition and add those to existing CamelContext using the method like.
context.addRouteDefinition().
I was looking the similar help and got the same suggestion from @Sikorski
For reference I gone through the files. org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler andorg.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sikorski please provide solution as i saw your similar post. Thanks a lot